# Mapping integers to strings in a given string space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Suppose I have an alphabet of 'abcd' and a maximum string length of 3. This gives me [85 possible strings](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+4%2a%2ai%2C+i%3D0+to+3), including the empty string. What I would like to do is map an integer in the range [0,85) to a string in my string space without using a lookup table. Something like this:

```
0 => ''
1 => 'a'
...
4 => 'd'
5 => 'aa'
6 => 'ab'
...
84 => 'ddd'
```

This is simple enough to do if the string is fixed length using this pseudocode algorithm:

```
str = ''
for i in 0..maxLen do
    str += alphabet[i % alphabet.length]
    i /= alphabet.length
done
```

I can't figure out a good, efficient way of doing it though when the length of the string could be anywhere in the range [0,3). This is going to be running in a tight loop with random inputs so I would like to avoid any unnecessary branching or lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift your index by one and ignore the empty string temporarily. So you'd map `0 -> "a", ..., 83 -> "ddd"`.

Then the mapping is

```
n -> base-4-encode(n - number of shorter strings)
```

With 26 symbols, that's the Excel-column-numbering scheme.

With `s` symbols, there are `s + s^2 + ... + s^l` nonempty strings of length at most `l`. Leaving aside the trivial case `s = 1`, that sum is (a partial sum of a geometric series) `s*(s^l - 1)/(s-1)`.

So, given `n`, find the largest `l` such that `s*(s^l - 1)/(s-1) <= n`, i.e.

```
l = floor(log((s-1)*n/s + 1) / log(s))
```

Then let `m = n - s*(s^l - 1)/(s-1)` and encode `m` as an `l+1`-symbol string in base `s` ('a' ~> 0, 'b' ~> 1, ...).

For the problem including the empty string, map 0 to the empty string and for `n > 0` encode `n-1` as above.

Comment: Your grasp of the maths involved is clearly a lot stronger than mine, but this is exactly what I was looking for; it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell

```
encode cs n = reverse $ encode' n where
  len = length cs
  encode' 0 = ""
  encode' n = (cs !! ((n-1) `mod` len)) : encode' ((n-1) `div` len)
```

Check:

> *Main> map (encode "abcd") [0..84] ["","a","b","c","d","aa","ab","ac","ad","ba","bb","bc","bd","ca","cb","cc","cd","da","db","dc","dd","aaa","aab","aac","aad","aba","abb","abc","abd","aca","acb","acc","acd","ada","adb","adc","add","baa","bab","bac","bad","bba","bbb","bbc","bbd","bca","bcb","bcc","bcd","bda","bdb","bdc","bdd","caa","cab","cac","cad","cba","cbb","cbc","cbd","cca","ccb","ccc","ccd","cda","cdb","cdc","cdd","daa","dab","dac","dad","dba","dbb","dbc","dbd","dca","dcb","dcc","dcd","dda","ddb","ddc","ddd"]

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the number of strings for each length: N0, N1, N2 & N3 (actually, you won't need N3).  Then, use those values to partition your space of integers: 0..N0-1 are length 0, N0..N0+N1-1 are length 1, etc.  Within each partition, you can use your fixed-length algorithm.

At worst, you've greatly reduced the size of your lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution:

```
    static string F(int x, int alphabetSize)
    {
        string ret = "";
        while (x > 0)
        {
            x--;
            ret = (char)('a' + (x % alphabetSize)) + ret;
            x /= alphabetSize;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

If you want to optimize this further, you may want to do something to avoid the string concatenations. For example, you could store the result into a preallocated char[] array.